# What does the syntax '%s' and '%d' mean as shorthand for calling a variable?

Tags: php, oop

What do '%s' and '%d' mean in this example?  It appears its shorthand for calling variables.  Does this syntax only work within a class?

```
// Class
class Building {
    // Object variables/properties
    private $number_of_floors = 5; // These buildings have 5 floors
    private $color;

    // Class constructor
    public function __construct($paint) {
        $this->color = $paint;
    }

    public function describe() {
        printf('This building has %d floors. It is %s in color.', 
            $this->number_of_floors, 
            $this->color
        );
    }
}
```

EDIT:  The part that is confusing to me is how does the compiler know which variable %d is referring to?  Does it just go in the order that the member variables were declared?

Comment: The manual explains this all very well.. See http://php.net/sprintf

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are format specifiers, meaning a variable of a specified type will be inserted into the output at that position. This syntax works outside of classes as well.

From the documentation:

> d - the argument is treated as an integer, and presented as a (signed)
> decimal number.
>
> s - the argument is treated as and presented as a string.

See the [manual on printf](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php). For a list of format specifiers, see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

Answer (score 1):

That's part of the printf method.  Those are placeholders for the variables that follow.  %d means treat it as a number.  %s means treat it as a string.

The list of variables that follow in the function call are used in the order they show up in the preceding string.

Answer (score 1):

`%s` means format as "string" and is replaced by the value in`$this->number_of_floors`

`%d` means format as "integer", and is being replaced by the value in`$this->color`

printf is a "classic" function that have been around for a while and are implemented in many programming languages.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf