# Mysql Wildcard not returning result

Tags: php, mysql, wildcard

Got a strange problem here. I have a search function where I am looking for patterns in strings of letters.

When I do a `SELECT` query with `%%%%dd` within a .php page it doesnt return any results, however when I do the same search using phpmyadmin I get 180 results.

What is odd is that queries with `%%%%ll` or `%%%%ww` within the .php page work exactly as expected, its just when the wildcard query ends with more than one d.

Below is a sample of the code that doesnt return anything.

```
$hf = "%%%%dd";

$searchDB = "SELECT *
         FROM st_grid
         WHERE home_last_five LIKE '$hf'";
```

Any help much appreciated

P

Comment: Can you show the code where you're executing this query? Also, do you get the same problem when you try characters other than "d" in the range 0-9 or a-f?

Comment: Could this be your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865673/what-does-the-syntax-s-and-d-mean-as-shorthand-for-calling-a-variable

Comment: What on Earth is the point in repeating a wildcard that matches "zero or more characters"?

Comment: Probably confusing `%` with `_`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070411/mysql-wildcards-and

Comment: I didnt realise that the % only needed to be entered once