# Read more link in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, hyperlink

I've been trying to change some read more buttons in my front page for a while now

[image]

I've narrowed down this HTML text.

```
printf('<p>%s</p>', get_the_excerpt($post->ID));
      printf('<a href="%s" class="button">Read more</a>', post_permalink($post->ID));
```

I was wondering how come the read more buttons/links don't have URLs? And what does Post ID mean?

Answer (score 3):

There's good info on the treatment of [Wordpress variables here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865673/what-does-the-syntax-s-and-d-mean-as-shorthand-for-calling-a-variable). In your case, the %s is a string variable within the printf that is being generated by the functions get_the_excerpt() and post_permalink()

Both of those functions are using the ID of the Post (Post ID) to retrieve the results to print.

Comment: So I would need to just change the ID of the post to the ID of the page I want it to lead to? Correct? I'm going to do some reading on this but what do you think?

Comment: That would redirect it to the specific post, yes. But you lose the dynamic functionality of the code and would have to update it every time you write a new post that uses this page/code.

Comment: Yes but I don't really care about the that seeing as I wont be updating the pages with post. Its more like, I want the links to lead to permanent articles in my site. So hypothetically, would inserting the URL of the pages I want it to lead to, work?

Comment: Oh, if you hard code the URL, then it will direct where ever you you want!

Answer (score 2):

from the code first line the %s = Post ID.

Post ID is getting an ID from one of your wordpress blog posts. It looks like your template is tied in to the blog post system.  I am guessing it is pulling from the latest or a feature post that has been set. It depends on your template / theme.

Answer (score 2):

The Url is `post_permalink($post->ID)` the post_permalink of post id.
In the following the `%s` represents the url of the post.

```
printf('<a href="%s" class="button">Read more</a>', post_permalink($post->ID));
```

Comment: Okay now heres another dillema. I have three read more buttons and only one of those codes, so that code works for all three of them I guess. How do I edit so that each read more button goes to a page of my design?

Comment: Yes but there are three read more buttons and only this code commands all three of them I think. But I want each of them to go to specific pages and not the ones they go to now.

Comment: You have to create your destination page (pagedestination.html or pagexxx.html). For the page number you'll ckeck the corresponding url and in your button you replace %s by the url.

Comment: Okay. One last question, is there a way to do this the way wordpress intended it? Because as far as I know you don't need to do code or HTML on wordpress, it does it for you. Do you know where in ther wordpress interface I can find this and get it done quickly?

Comment: In some previous version it was very simple, but now as said @WebbySmart this theme is very tied with wordpress. You have to read documentation. I am sorry

Comment: Its okay, at least you gave me a definite answer :). I guess I have to do some wordpress reading